# Uploading GeoJSON to Mapbox - 'expected EOF' error

Tags: qgis, geojson, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to add a newline geoJSON to mapbox studio but I keep getting the following error:

> *Input failed. Parse error on line 1: ...34, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }{ "type": "Feature", ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got
> '{' on line 0*

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? - I'm fairly new to this.
Here is my geoJson:

```
 { "type": "Feature",
    "properties": 
    { "Shape_Leng": 51175.326008900003, 
    "Shape_Area": 82572468.702800006, 
    "Field": 7989.09 

}, 
    "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon",
 "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -62.3254956, -9.2975334, 0.0 ], [ -62.3809389, -9.3645961, 0.0 ]........ [ -62.3254956, -9.2975334, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }


    { "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "Shape_Leng": 51420.598936100003,
 "Shape_Area": 109737080.03399999, 
"Field": 10604.5 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", 
"coordinates": [ [ [ [ -62.2553282, -9.4713409, 0.0 ], [ -62.2545357, -9.5727042, 0.0 ], .....[ -62.2553282, -9.4713409, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }


    { "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "Shape_Leng": 109761.94360599999, 
"Shape_Area": 185731461.11099997, 
"Field": 17929.2 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", 
"coordinates": [ [ [ [ -62.0081522, -9.5956181, 0.0 ],.....[ -62.0081522, -9.5956181, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple features, you must have an array of features within `FeatureCollection`.

Your GeoJSON should then look something like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {"type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Shape_Leng": 51175.326008900003, 
        "Shape_Area": 82572468.702800006, 
        "Field": 7989.09 
      }, 
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -62.3254956, -9.2975334, 0.0 ], ........ [ -62.3254956, -9.2975334, 0.0 ] ] ] ]
      }
    },
    {"type": "Feature", 
      "properties": {
        "Shape_Leng": 51420.598936100003,
        "Shape_Area": 109737080.03399999, 
        "Field": 10604.5
      }, 
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon", 
        "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -62.2553282, -9.4713409, 0.0 ], .....[ -62.2553282, -9.4713409, 0.0 ] ] ] ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much